# Rotate an image about a specific pixel in python

Tags: python, image, astronomy, image-rotation

How can I rotate an image about a specific pixel in Python? I am trying to de-rotate a set of images of the night sky. Since the stars rotate around Polaris, I could define Polaris as the center of rotation and rotate each image to line up the stars.

Comment: Once you work out how to rotate an image about a specific pixel, how do you programmatically define the location of Polaris?

Comment: Polaris does not move (or moves very little), and therefore is always on the same pixel. So I can just define it's location in pixel coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In phadej's answer the transformation between the old and new coordinates of a point on the image is an [affine transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation).

[PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) (Python Imaging Library) has an image method called `transform` which can perform an affine transformation of an image.

The documentation for `transform` is near the bottom of this [page](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm).

Answer (score 0):

With a little math: if each image's pixel position is vector `a`, and position of Polaris is `p`, then new position `new_p` is

```
new_p = a + R * (a-p)
```

where R is [Rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

There will be problem, as `new_p` is probably not an integer valued position-vector. You
can do it backwards. For each pixel of rotated image apply the inverse of above transform,
than you will get pixel from original image. As it could be not integer also, sample the neighbor pixels like in [wu-pixels](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/graphics/x_wupixl.htm) (the amount of dot spread around can be used as the sampling weight).

Comment: I'm sure there is some library to do it for you, but it's nice programming exercice. For example `imagemagick` has this kind of "distortion" built-in: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=gcvcqder3prdmhc6d8m6gk38v4#distort